# Oracle SQL Developer diamon icon in model

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

I have created model in **Oracle SQL Developer**, in bottom there are 2 icons

1 is key (which is primary key) , 2nd is diamond ? what diamond showing ?

Answer (score 9):

The diamond items show you the INDEXES on that table.

[image]

The red asterisk character to the left of the column name indicates the column has a NOT NULL constraint.

If we pull up the table in the database, we can see the indexes list and the model diagram side by side to verify.

[image]

In Oracle, a PRIMARY_KEY constraint automatically creates an INDEX of the same name, UNLESS you already have an INDEX and you tell the PRIMARY_KEY constraint to just re-use your existing INDEX.

Answer (score -2):

The diamond is showing that it is a NOT NULL field.